# How to understand two named types are identical in golang

Tags: types, go

The rules of [type identity](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_identity) state that:

`Two named types are identical if their type names originate in the same TypeSpec`

I don't quite understand how two type names originate in the same TypeSpec. Can you explain it  or show me an example?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Only one type name can originate from a TypeSpec.  That's kind of the point.  So

```
type Foo int64
var x Foo
var y Foo
```

then both `Foo`s originate in the same TypeSpec, so they are identical `Foo`s.

However, if you have two different files (in different packages):

a.go:

```
type Foo int64
var x Foo
```

b.go:

```
type Foo int64
var y Foo
```

Then the two `Foo`s in this situation are not identical.  Even though they are the same type name, they originated from different TypeSpecs.  The consequence of this is that the types of `x` and `y` are not identical (and thus `x = y` without a cast is not allowed).

Answer (score 0):

`Two named types are identical if their type names originate in the same TypeSpec`

In fact, you can't have two named types that are identical in Go code. Because in Go code, `originate in the same TypeSpec` means the same type. It's meaningless to say one type is identical to itself.

But we do have different named types which are identical: byte and uint8; rune and int32, according to 
[the spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Numeric_types)

It's only possible to do this in the compiler for the predeclared types.

Refer to [the discussion in golang nuts](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/Golang-nuts/7d_B1AhI5ho/JXhgmejLBQAJ)

Note:
In Go 1.9, there'll be a new feature called: type alias/alias declarations. With this feature, it becomes possible to declare different named types which are identical. Refer to [talk about Go 1.9](https://talks.golang.org/2017/state-of-go-may.slide#11)