# Type assertion failed when using two different (but identical) types

Tags: go, type-assertion

I have this code

```
package main

import "fmt"

type MyType int

func main() {
    var i interface{} = 12

    f := i.(MyType)

    fmt.Println(f)
}
```

However, I get this error:

```
panic: interface conversion: interface is int, not main.MyType
```

However, int is, in this case, the same as MyType. Is there any way to do this without using the same type?

Comment: `var i interface{} = MyType(12)`

Comment: related(?): [How to understand two named types are identical in golang](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20089670/how-to-understand-two-named-types-are-identical-in-golang)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're not identical types. As the runtime tells you, one is `int` and one is `MyType`. Go has a very specific definition of identical.

Straight from the spec:

> A type declaration binds an identifier, the type name, to a new type
>   that has the same underlying type as an existing type, and operations
>   defined for the existing type are also defined for the new type. The
>   new type is different from the existing type.

https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_identity

https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_declarations

https://golang.org/ref/spec#Types

You can easily convert between the two, `MyType(12)` works just fine, but type assertion is different from converting: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions

If you'd like to do some reading about interfaces and types and all of that fun stuff, these are both super helpful:

http://blog.golang.org/laws-of-reflection

http://research.swtch.com/interfaces